# Dynamically set parameter type of function literal

Tags: scala

Suppose I have something like this:

```
abstract class MyContainer[E]

abstract class MyClass[T] {
  def myFunction: Unit = {
    (myParam: MyContainer[T]) => Empty
  }
}
```

Now suppose I create implementations for these:

```
class StringContainer[String] extends MyContainer[String]

class StringClass extends MyClass[String]
```

Is there any way to dynamically modify the type of myParameter. **without** overriding myFunction, so that myFunction during runtime effectively behaves in the following way?

```
abstract class StringClass[String] {
  def myFunction: Unit = {
    (myParam: StringContainer) => Empty
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question I realised I had completely misunderstood proper use of generics in Scala. I am posting a working example here just for the benefit of anyone else who may come across the same mistake:

```
abstract class MyContainer[E]

abstract class MyClass[T, C <: MyContainer[T]] {
  def myFunction: Unit = {
    (myParam: C) => Empty
  }
}
```

and then simply:

```
class StringContainer[String] extends MyContainer[String]

class StringClass extends MyClass[String, StringContainer]
```